# I need to have each line of a file run in a subshell of its own

Tags: shell-script, subshell

I have a script that works fine, but runs in series.

I would like to have the script take each line from a text file and run/spawn that line in a subshell and then move onto the next line and so on.

I need the subshell for two reasons:
Firstly, to have the job run in parallel rather than serially, making it run far faster.
Secondly to monitor the output of the given command and return the exit code from the remote systems.

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this please?

For a bit of background, each line of the text file is a gathering of ssh commands that is run on a remote system with options, functions gathered from user input and another input file, so each line in the scripts generated output is a self contained command for a server.

I call the script via the `/bin/bash $temp_file` action.

The script example would be something like:

```
sshpass -p <PASSWORD> ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22 USER@HOST.COM  'cat /etc/hostname  ;echo 'START';echo `date +%Y-%m-%d` ; echo <PASSWORD> |sudo -S yum update -y; cat /etc/hostname ;echo 'FINISH';echo `date +%Y-%m-%d` ;echo '';echo ''
```

This is simply an example and the commands to run such as the `yum update -y` with echos and dates I have used here, would be replaced by either a single command or using `;` or `$$` to separate them.

I appreciate there are a lot of characters in the line that could cause an issue.

Comment: Is each line complete, or can there be multi-line commands such as if/then/else/fi or for or while loops? Are there any lines which consist of only comments? Are there any variables being set and then used? Can you use `bash` or `zsh` or are you restricted to POSIX `sh`?

Comment: Yes each line is complete, there are no comments, no for loops etc. i could simply pull each line and run it from the cli manually.
The output that i need to run and the script itself are written in bash.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add example input lines and an example script. It might be enough to just add `&` to the end of each line or, better, run the whole thing with GNU `parallel`, but we can't know without more details.

Comment: You'd better use Ansible for that kind of jobs. Ansible is build from scratch for parallel SSH jobs.

Comment: Be careful not to swamp your system...

Answer (score 11):

GNU Parallel is built for this:

```
parallel --joblog my.log < myfile.sh
```

`--sshlogin/--sshloginfile`, `--jobs N`, `--tag`, `--linebuffer`, and possibly `--nonall` may also be useful. You would have to divulge a bit more about the remote jobs you want to run to determine which will be relevant.

Comment: I ended up going with this option as it provided an instant easy fix to my issue.

Answer (score 7):

You can just read each line and use `eval` to evaluate it.

```
IFS=""
while read -r line; do
   eval "( $line )"
done < command_file
```

does the minimum you have asked for, i.e. running each line in a subshell.

Comment: Thanks Icarus, i will give that a try.

Comment: @roaima `( $line )` runs the command resulting from split+glob on `$line`, that's not evaluating the contents as shell code. For instance, on a line like `echo '+ * +'` and with the default value of `$IFS`, that would run `echo`, with `'+`, the list of non-hidden files in the current directory and `+'` as arguments.

Comment: I'd use `(eval " $line")` to make sure the code evaluation is self contained in a subshell. For instance, if `$line` was `uname); cd /; (uname`, yours would not run `cd` in a subshell and mine would report an error as expected.

Comment: Sorry yes of course

Comment: This still runs the lines sequentially. Gnu parallel is the best answer, but perhaps backgrounding the lines would work instead of taking the OP's question literally (subshells). `eval "$line" &`

Comment: I did try this, but it only ran the first line of commands for some reason, maybe due to a character in the command input. I have added more info in to the OP. Thanks all who have responded so far.

Comment: Note the question has been edited to add the requirement that the jobs run in parallel since my answer. Adding an "&" to the string being constructed for the eval will probably handle this. We now have an example line, and we see it is running multiple commands on a remote host, and probably the desire is to keep all the output together. Ansible and its competitors (e.g. salt, puppet, chef) is probably the right answer to this modified question.